# Instruments .trace file issues

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

- When I am checking out the test-scripts from SVN(files committed by
  my friend), I don't know why the scripts are not editable, play
  script and stop script options are disabled and Recording is not
  happening at all.
- When I am creating a new Automation project an importing the same
  script files then it is working fine.

**What could be the reason of a not working .trace file committed by someone else? What could be the possible solution?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer. But if you open the content of the .trace file, there is actually a template file. The location of the instrument template are different same times for different users depends on which version of the xcode you installed. Maybe the template file giving the path to the template on your friend's is different than the path to the template on your computer. Just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you should check all the header path like user Header path, If header path will correctly defined, You also should check wether you use correct version I mean your all script can able to communicate on all device or not,

And you can check your .trace file hear

Go for Finder, get context menu on file, select "Show Package Contents". From a command-line shell, just navigate to the file as if it were a directory.

Hope It will Help